# Which graph will be appropriate for the visualization task?

Tags: visualization, data, pandas, plotting

I have some terminal charging values for US and CHINA 
comes in a pandas DataFrame like the following,

```
       value country  
0      550.0     USA        
1      820.0   CHINA        
2      835.0   CHINA        
3      600.0   USA        
4      775.0   CHINA        
5      785.0   USA        
6      790.0   USA
```

This is the sample data and I have in total 5K+ entries. The data is cleared for the outliers and needs to be visualized. What kind of visualization can I use to plot my data meaningfully?

Comment: What specific visualization task do you need? Outliers detection or something else?

Comment: My instruction is `The list of values per country should be visualised in a meaningful way, identifying the amount of good/bad charges present in the system.` I  have cleared the `outliers` earlier and this data is good. I thought the `comparable visualization per country` would be great while I can manually calculate the percentage of the outliers per country and store using some method.

Comment: asymmetric beanplot maybe? [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13570629/6020255) + [statsmodels implementation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.beanplot.html) (use 'side' argument with 'left' and 'right')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this?

```
df.hist(by='country', bins=50)
```

If you want to plot these histograms in the same figure, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539195/multiple-histograms-in-pandas).

### References

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to identify good and bad charge times then the points themselves are important.

I would have my x-axis be my country names and then simply plot the charge times on the y-axis as scattered points.

This will give you scattered data in the y-direction digitized for each country.

I think you will be able to extract a lot of meaningful information from this plot for comparing different countries such as: max, min, approx. mean, etc..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is your objective.

Since you have so many values, you may want to plot some summary data, so you can use either two [Distplots](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html#seaborn.distplot) in a FacetGrid to have the two countries side by side or even better a [Boxplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot).

If the order of the appearance of the values matters you can try plot them as two different lines with the values on the y-axis by using FactorPlot.

(All the mentioned plots above are part of the Seaborn library)